# Десериализация JSON C#

Tags: c#, json

Есть ответ от сервера вида {"name":"Jonh","lastName":"Smith"},{"name":"Rick","lastName":"Grimes"}. И т.д. всего около 30 объектов.
Сейчас реализация далека от идеала,и на один объект идёт один запрос:

```
var rick = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://127.0.0.1/api/v3/dict/lastname?name=Rick");
```

Затем десериализую,и отправляю в класс

```
 public class Rick
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }
```

И затем спокойно использую в коде дальше. Как можно упростить это? Текущая реализация довольно медленная.

Сервер отдаёт все объекты по запросу http://127.0.0.1/api/v3/dict/lastname

Comment: Если это ваше API - то вам и карты в руки. Что мешает получить список объектов, а не на каждый объект или на каждое свойство делать отдельный запрос?

Comment: @AK нет,api не мой. Адрес упростил для наглядности

Comment: Мгм, ясно. Если я правильно понимаю ситуацию, то сделать в этом случае мало что можно, только обращаться к разработчикам API c предложениями уменьшить число запросов. С ваших слов я делаю вывод, что основные потери времени уходят именно на сетевое общение, оно много больше, чем десериализация json. Посмотрите ещё раз документацию - нет ли ещё каких методов, чтобы выгребать данные пачкой с сервера за раз, а не делать несколько запросов. Вполне возможно, что-то можно выиграть за счёт распаралеливания запросов.

Comment: @AK все объекты скопом можно получить через http://127.0.0.1/api/v3/dict/lastname,как и писал в вопросе. 
Ответом приходит:  {"name":"Jonh","lastName":"Smith"},{"name":"Rick","lastName":"Grimes"} и ещё 30 таких объектов.

Comment: Где-то есть эталонная закрывашка на эту тему от EvgeniyZ, но опять не могу найти - написал в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, у вас приходит не  `{"name":"Jonh","lastName":"Smith"},{"name":"Rick","lastName":"Grimes"}`, а `[ {"name":"Jonh","lastName":"Smith"},{"name":"Rick","lastName":"Grimes"}]` - иначе это невалидный json.

Ну, а что тогда сложного? Десериализация в одну строчку при помощи Json.Net:

```
var data = "[{\"name\":\"Jonh\",\"lastName\":\"Smith\"},{\"name\":\"Rick\",\"lastName\":\"Grimes\"}]";
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rick[]>(data);
```

Ваш результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Как потом обращаться допустим при name=Rick получить его lastName

```
var obj = deserialized.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.name, "Rick"));
obj.Dump();
obj.lastName.Dump();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да,всё верно. Скобы не поствил.
Вот до этого дошёл,а как потом таскать конкретные значения? Он же при десериализации все объекты загонит в класс. В этом проблема была. Как потом обращаться допустим к при name=Rick получить его lastName

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT Без `[]` ответ сервера будет невалидным json'ом.

Comment: @A K Да,всё верно. Скобы не поствил. Вот до этого дошёл,а как потом таскать конкретные значения? Он же при десериализации все объекты загонит в класс. В этом проблема была. Как потом обращаться допустим при name=Rick получить его lastName

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT Например, при помощи linq. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: а что за метод расширения Dump? директива на linq и Newtonsoft.Json указана,а в списке такого нет

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT `Dump()` - это метод сторонней программы `linqpad`, вам он не нужен, не обращайте на него внимания